# trying to find a div relative to a button that was clicked

Tags: jquery

when I click the button of class .weightAdjBtn I want to append some HTML to the div .wAdjWrapper

```
<fieldset class="weightAdj">
    <legend>weight adjustment (tons) <button class="weightAdjBtn">+</button></legend>
    <div class="wAdjWrapper">
            <div class="wAdjDiv">
                <input type="text" name="adjInWeight" class="wa numbersOnly ibTally">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

the function is:

```
function addWeightAdj(obj){

    var jin="<div class='wAdjDiv'>";
    jin+="<input type='text' name='adjInWeight' class='wa numbersOnly ibTally'>";
    jin+="</div>";

    $(this).find(".wAdjWrapper").append(jin);   


}
```

but I it doesn't. 
I've also tried

```
$(this).parent().find(".wAdjWrapper").append(jin);
```

I have verified that the function is firing when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parent()` in this case is the `legend` element, which (like the `button`) doesn't contain any `div` elements.

You need to search the enclosing `fieldset`:

```
$(this).closest('fieldset').find(".wAdjWrapper").append(jin);
```

Comment: I can't get that to work either. I have a test here:

http://jsfiddle.net/fxtz5859/1/

Comment: Nothing in your jsFiddle (nor in your sample code) would cause the function to be called when the button is clicked. An updated fiddle that actually adds the handler: http://jsfiddle.net/fxtz5859/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:-

```
<fieldset class="weightAdj">
    <legend>weight adjustment (tons) <button class="weightAdjBtn">+</button></legend>
    <div class="wAdjWrapper">
            <div class="wAdjDiv">
                <input type="text" name="adjInWeight" class="wa numbersOnly ibTally">
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clr">
    </div>
</fieldset>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.weightAdjBtn', function() {
        var jin="<div class='wAdjDiv'>";
        jin+="<input type='text' name='adjInWeight' class='wa numbersOnly ibTally'>";
        jin+="</div>";
        jQuery( ".wAdjWrapper" ).append( jin );
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think the problem with this is that I will have multiple .wAdjWrapper

Comment: But you are appending a div with class wAdjDiv

Comment: @Shawn You can also use `jQuery( ".wAdjWrapper" ).last().append( jin );` For last occurance

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer the below code.

```
<body>
<div class="a">
    <button id="add" onclick="Add()">Add</button>
    <div class="b">


    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

```
<script>

function Add() {

    if($("#add").parent().hasClass('a'))
    {
            $('div.b').append("<p>Test</p>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a couple things wrong, but got it to work here:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxtz5859/4/)

```
$(obj).parent().parent().find(".wAdjWrapper").append(jin);
```